# Jquery autoincrement value and detect for reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I start with value i=0, and the max value it´s 4, when script detect value it´s the same as 4 must restart or reset value of "i" to 0 as default value

```js
i = 0;

function loading() {

  if (i == 4) {
    i = 0;
  }

  jQuery("#text").show(1000).hide(1000, function() {
    reloading();
  });
}


function reloading() {
  setInterval("loading()", 2000);
  alert("ok" + i);
  i++;
}


loading();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text" style="position:relative;width:150px;height:150px;background-color:red;display:none;"></div>
```

I try do for show the div 4 times and reset to 0 and start other time 0,1,2,3, and reset 0 and start other time, but not works, i don´t know why happend this, i think the code it´s ok but sure something bad

Thank´s for the help in advanced

Comment: pelase don't use `setInterval("loading()", 2000);` use `setInterval(loading, 2000);` instead

Comment: This looks like a close duplicate to something you already asked.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361567/jquery-repeat-set-inteval-when-function-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you called your function `loading()` to start the animation variable `i` values started from 1, not 0 and hence it goes for 3 times only and then get reset to 0.(because after 3 iterations `i` become 4)

So increase 4 to 5 in `if(i==4){` and you will good to go

Working snippet:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text" style="position:relative;width:150px;height:150px;background-color:red;display:none;"></div>

<script>
    i=0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        loading();
    });
    function loading(){
      if(i==5){
        i=0;
      }
      jQuery("#text").show(1000).hide(1000,function(){reloading();});
    }
    function reloading(){
      setInterval("loading()",2000);
      alert("ok"+i);
      i++;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosMariñoFernández  glad to help you :):)